# R nls singular gradient to find a sigmoid function

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to find an optimal sigmoid functional that adjust to my data (at the end of this post). But there is an error: Error in nls(cumulativo ~ f(eixox, phi1, phi2, phi3), start = st, data = data,  : singular gradient

Any suggestions ?

```
library("ggplot2")

data<-structure(list(cumulativo = c(2, 3, 17, 191, 819, 1699, 2679, 
                          3907, 5535, 7254, 9226, 11543, 13809, 15542, 16852, 17709, 18246, 
                          18661, 18976, 19256, 19412, 19539, 19639), eixox = 1994:2016), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
plot(cumulativo~eixox, data=data)

st <- list(phi1=20000,phi2=-5,phi3=.0005)
f <- function(x,phi1,phi2,phi3) {phi1/(1 + exp(-phi3 * x - phi2))}
curvaS<-nls(cumulativo~f(eixox,phi1,phi2,phi3),start=st,data=data,trace=TRUE)
```

[image: dvd.csv]

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular questions should be reproducible. Do not use directory names that are specific to your platform or setup.  Do not use images since they can only be used if tediously retyped..  Instead show the output of `dput(X)` where X is your input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your function definition. It should be

```
f <- function(x, phi1, phi2, phi3) {phi1/(1 + exp(-phi3 * (x - phi2)))}
```

Where `phi1` is the upper bound, `phi2` is the midpoint of the sigmoid curve, and `phi3` is the rate. Note the extra parentheses so that `phi2` is subtracted from `x` and then multiplied by `-phi3`. Now pick reasonable starting values and run `nls`:

```
st <- list(phi1=20000, phi2=2005, phi3=.5)
curvaS <- nls(cumulativo~f(eixox, phi1, phi2, phi3), start=st, data=data, trace=TRUE)
# 20466691 :  20000.0  2005.0     0.5
# 1334673 :  19669.7851882  2004.2327533     0.4406048
# 902806.6 :  19566.0810794  2004.1449741     0.4639131
# 901808.4 :  19578.7102128  2004.1498061     0.4637724
# 901808.4 :  19578.7652076  2004.1498401     0.4637683
curvaS
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: cumulativo ~ f(eixox, phi1, phi2, phi3)
#    data: data
#       phi1       phi2       phi3 
# 19578.7652  2004.1498     0.4638 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 901808
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 0.000003139
```

Finally, plot:

```
plot(cumulativo~eixox, data=data)
pred <- predict(curvaS)
lines(data$eixox, pred)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: it works !! thanks a lot, in your command i need to use start=t

Comment: That was a typo on the first line. I've corrected it.